# Redis with custom data dir: systemd config file changed automatically?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, redis

I'm running Redis 4.0.9 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with a custom data dir for the RBD file.

To make this work, besides updating the `dir` in `redis.conf` to the new location, I also had to update `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service` and set:

`ReadWriteDirectories=-/my/custom/data/dir`

(as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814351/failed-opening-the-rdb-file-read-only-file-system)

Everything was working fine, until suddenly one day Redis started giving the `Failed opening the RDB file backup.rdb (in server root dir /var/lib/redis) for saving: Read-only file system` error again, as if the `ReadWriteDirectories` was not set to the new data dir.

I checked `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service` and the `ReadWriteDirectories` entry I added was indeed gone. I added it back and, after restarting, Redis works fine again and can sava data.

My question is: how could `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service` change and my `ReadWriteDirectories` line disappear? I am the only one with access to this machine. Is this file overwritten automatically in some cases? Can I disable that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not meant to edit the systemd service files shipped with packages. These can be replaced at any time, e.g. when the package is updated.

Instead, you should create override files containing the changes you want to make. These will be preserved because they are not part of the system package which gets updated.

The simple way to do this is to run `systemctl edit redis`. This will create an override drop-in file `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service.d/override.conf`, in which you can place your changes (and the proper section):

```
[Service]
ReadWriteDirectories=-/my/custom/data/dir
```

You may also create that directory and place files ending in `.conf` in it manually. But do not leave the directory empty, as this will disable the service.

In either case, run `systemctl daemon-reload` and you are ready to restart your service.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the redis.conf `dir` param, it was giving me `Can't chdir to '/new_dir/redis': Permission denied`.

This was because of `SELinux` permissions. https://help.hostry.com/knowledge-base/how-to-set-selinux-to-permissive-mode/

Run this command: `sudo setenforce 0`. This will start working.

Though this is not a correct way to do it. You should create config to allow redis to access that folder in SELinux.